# Copy all files in a folder, including files in sub folders

Tags: google-apps-script

I have to copy the file of each subfolder which is there in original folder but what is happening currently it is copying file of last subfolder and rest of the subfolder it is creating is empty but in original there are file which it is not copying.

For example there is one main folder Amit->amit1 subfolder->amit2 subfolder like this currently it is copying file of only amit 2 subfolder only and rest of the folder is empty

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var scriptproperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

function authorize() {
    spreadsheet.toast("Enter Folder ID and  Select GDrive: Copy Folder->  Make a Copy", "", -1);

}


function onOpen() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var menuEntries = [{
            name: "1. Authorize",
            functionName: "authorize"
        }, {
            name: "2. Make a Copy",
            functionName: "findRootFolder"
        }

    ];
    ss.addMenu("GDrive: Copy Folder", menuEntries);
    spreadsheet.toast("Select GDrive: Copy Folder-> Authorize. This is an One Time Action.", "Get Started", -1);
}

function findRootFolder() {
    var folderId = sheet.getRange("B5").getValue();
    var folderId = folderId.toString().trim();
    var start = new Date();

    try {

        var topFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);

        deletekeys();
        spreadsheet.toast("Copy Process Has Started. Please Wait...", "Started", -1);
        getFolders_(topFolder.getName(), topFolder);
        spreadsheet.toast("Folder Has Been Copied Successfully. Please Check Your Google Drive Now.", "Success", -1);
    } catch (e) {
        Browser.msgBox("Error", "Sorry, Error Occured: " + e.toString(), Browser.Buttons.OK);
        spreadsheet.toast("Error Occurred :( Please make sure you Entered Folder ID in B5 Cell.", "Oops!", -1);
    }

}

function getFolders_(path, container) {

    var folders = container.getFolders();

    var count = 0;
    while (folders.hasNext()) {
        count++;
        var folder = folders.next();
    }

    var folderCount = count;
    var fileslist = container.getFiles();
    var fileCountFind = 0;
    while (fileslist.hasNext()) {
        fileCountFind++;
        var file = fileslist.next();
        Logger.log(file.getName());
    }
    var fileCount = fileCountFind;
    var files = container.getFiles();

    Logger.log("container.getName() " + container.getName() + "| folder length " + folderCount + "| files length " + fileCount);

    if (folderCount <= 0) {

        if (fileCount > 0) {
            Logger.log("Just Files Found Loop");
            copyfiles_(container.getName(), files);
        }
    }

    if (folderCount) {
        Logger.log("If loop, Folders Found");
        var folders = container.getFolders();

        while (folders.hasNext()) {

            var folder = folders.next();
            copy_(container.getName(), folder.getName(), files);
            var thisFolder = folder.getName();
            var thisPath = path + "/" + thisFolder;
            Logger.log("Folder Name:" + folder.getName());
            getFolders_(thisPath, folder);

        }

    }
    return;
}

function copy_(containername, childname, files)

{

    if (scriptproperties.getProperty(containername + "copy")) {
        Logger.log("if");
        var parentcontainer = DriveApp.getFolderById(scriptproperties.getProperty(containername + "copy"));

        if (!scriptproperties.getProperty(containername + "processed")) {
            /*process, copy files*/

            while (files.hasNext()) {
                var file = files.next();
                var newFile = file.makeCopy(file.getName(), parentcontainer);
               //parentcontainer.addFile(newFile);
                DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(newFile);
                Utilities.sleep(2000);
            }




        }

        scriptproperties.setProperty(containername + "processed", "true");
        var childfolder = parentcontainer.createFolder(childname + "_copy");
        var childfolderid = childfolder.getId();
        scriptproperties.setProperty(childname + "copy", childfolderid);

    } else {

        Logger.log("else");
        var parentfold = DriveApp.createFolder(containername + "_copy");
        var parentfoldid = parentfold.getId();
        scriptproperties.setProperty(containername + "copy", parentfoldid);



        if (!scriptproperties.getProperty(containername + "processed")) {
            /*process, copy files*/

            while (files.hasNext()) {
                var file = files.next();
                var newFile = file.makeCopy(file.getName(), parentfold);
            //  parentfold.addFile(newFile);
                DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(newFile);
                Utilities.sleep(2000);
            }

        }

        scriptproperties.setProperty(containername + "processed", "true");
        var childfolder = parentfold.createFolder(childname + "_copy");
        var childfolderid = childfolder.getId();
        scriptproperties.setProperty(childname + "copy", childfolderid);

    }
    Logger.log("Container Name: " + containername + "||" + " Child Name: " + childname);
}

function copyfiles_(containername, files) {
    if (scriptproperties.getProperty(containername + "copy")) {
        Logger.log("If Loop, Just files found- down");
        var parentcontainer = DriveApp.getFolderById(scriptproperties.getProperty(containername + "copy"));

        if (!scriptproperties.getProperty(containername + "processed")) {

            while (files.hasNext()) {
                var file = files.next();
                var newFile = file.makeCopy(file.getName(), parentcontainer);
              //parentcontainer.addFile(newFile);
                DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(newFile);
                Utilities.sleep(2000);
            }
        }
        scriptproperties.setProperty(containername + "processed", "true");

    } else {

        Logger.log("Else Loop, Just files found");
        var parentfold = DriveApp.createFolder(containername + "_copy");
        var parentfoldid = parentfold.getId();
        scriptproperties.setProperty(containername + "copy", parentfoldid);

        if (!scriptproperties.getProperty(containername + "processed")) {

            while (files.hasNext()) {
                var file = files.next();
                var newFile = file.makeCopy(file.getName(), parentfold);
              //parentfold.addFile(newFile);
                DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(newFile);
                Utilities.sleep(2000);
            }



        }
        scriptproperties.setProperty(containername + "processed", "true");
    }

}

function deletekeys() {
    scriptproperties.deleteAllProperties();
}
```

Comment: BELOW ARE THE STEPS YOU NEED TO FOLLOW 1. Make a copy of the project (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EkwRtcyVKzADEzoEfZdvqJ4iEm9VBJARiZs0JURDlJE/edit#gid=0).(2.) Next click Yes, make a copy link
(3)Click GDrive: Copy Folder menu next to help. And select Authorize. Click OK then Accept. This is a one time activity.
In B5 cell copy, paste the folder ID which you noted down in previous step.
Finally select Make a Copy option from the menu.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I understand that you want to copy the **files** in your file structure ignoring the **folders**.
I came up with this sample of a recursive function that goes from the passed folder to the last subfolder and copies each file it encounters and moves it to the main folder (the one passed by parameter, not the main drive folder):

```
 function myFunction() {
  
  var fromFolder = '***your folder's ID***';
  var toFolder = fromFolder
  
  // THIS WILL MAKE COPIES OF ALL THE FILES IGNORING THE FOLDER STRUCTURE INTO toFolder
  copyFiles(fromFolder, toFolder)
}

function copyFiles(idToSearch, mainId) {
  var file = Drive.Files.get(idToSearch)
  
  //CHECKS IF THE FOLDER PASSED IS AN ACTUAL FOLDER OR A FILE
  if (file.mimeType != 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder') {
    Logger.log(file.parents[0].id)
    
    // COPY THE FILE
    var copyFile = DriveApp.getFileById(file.id).makeCopy();
    
    
    //Drive.Files.copy(file, file.id)
    
    //UPDATES THE FILE PARENT TO THE ROOT FOLDER
    var optionalArgs = {   
      "addParents": mainId,
      "removeParents": copyFile.getParents().next().getId()
    }
    Drive.Files.patch(Drive.Files.get(copyFile.getId()), copyFile.getId(), optionalArgs)
    
  } else {
    
    var fileChildren = Drive.Children.list(file.id)
    
    for(var i = 0; i < fileChildren.items.length; i++) {
      copyFiles(fileChildren.items[i].id, mainId)
    }
  }
  
}
```

If that was not what you needed, please let me know.

---

## Edit

I have found and tried this code and it works.

Credit: [Make a Copy of Folders in Google Drive with Google Scripts](https://ctrlq.org/code/19979-copy-folders-drive)

```
function start() {
  
  var sourceFolder = "Copy folder structure";
  var targetFolder = "New folder structure Copy";
  
  var source = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(sourceFolder)
  var target = DriveApp.createFolder(targetFolder);

  if (source.hasNext()) {
    copyFolder(source.next(), target);
  }
  
}

function copyFolder(source, target) {

  var folders = source.getFolders();
  var files   = source.getFiles();
  
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    file.makeCopy(file.getName(), target);
  }
  
  while(folders.hasNext()) {
    var subFolder = folders.next();
    var folderName = subFolder.getName();
    var targetFolder = target.createFolder(folderName);
    copyFolder(subFolder, targetFolder);
  }  
  
}
```

Comment: no i want all the subfolders and with the files in that folder same which is in original folder means i want exact copy of original one.For example i have one main folder name AMITFOLDER in that there is one subfolder name AMITSUBFOLDER under which there is another subfolder name AMITSUBFOLDER1 under which there is another subfolder name AMITSUBFOLDER2 and in this folder there are some files stored.so i want exact replica of this.Currently what i am getting is only folder and subfolder but i am not getting files that i have mentioned above